Pyqtgraph is not plotting
I im taking some data for my y axis from seperate thread,the framework i use is pyqt6 and the plot lib is pyqtgraph .
My problem is that i return the data with a signal and i succesfully receive them in my function but when it comes the time to plot the it simply not working ...
Why ? Its a sync error ? Do i have any bugs ?
Thanks .
My code is :
class PlotScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot_widget.setYRange(0, 5)
        self.plot_widget.setXRange(1546, 1558)
        layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget, 1)

...............
 @pyqtSlot(list)
    def on_data_ready(self, AUData):
        self.AUData = AUData
        time.sleep(1)

        # Convert lists to NumPy arrays
        x_data_array = np.array(self.x_data)
        AUData_array = np.array(self.AUData)

        if AUData_array.size > 0:
            if len(x_data_array) == len(AUData_array):
                self.plot_widget.setXRange(min(x_data_array), max(x_data_array))
                self.plot_widget.setYRange(min(AUData_array), max(AUData_array))
                self.plot_widget.clear()
                self.plot_widget.plot(
                    x_data_array, AUData_array, pen=pg.mkPen("b", width=2)
                )
                self.plot_widget.repaint()
            else:
                print(
                    f"x and AUData length mismatch! (len(x): {len(x_data_array)}, len(AUData): {len(AUData_array)})"
                )
        else:
            print("Error")




I've tried to plot them as lists also but no luck .. if i put random data its plotting them tho

Please provide a more comprehensive [mre] (and please do read that link, we do not need the full code). Also remove time.sleep() as blocking functions (or loops) should never be used in UI calls.
